# Panel is Not Hiding in Timer tick event in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using an updatepanel on my web page in which timer trigger is enabled. Now in timer tick event i want to hide/show another panel according to conditions. But Problem is that Hide/Show is not working in timer tick event. My code is here:-

```
protected void ChatTextTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "TextBox1slide", 
                                        "button11Clicked();", true);
    if (lblHired.Text == "Hiring")
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rd = new SqlCommand("Select IsApproved from Chat where id=" +
                           Int32.Parse(lblID.Text), con).ExecuteReader();
        rd.Read();
        if (rd["IsApproved"].ToString() == "Approved")
        {
            lblHired.Text = "Hired";
            Panel3.Visible = false;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add your `hide and show` code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether your panel3 placed inside of update panel. So that it will triggers all your controls which are placed inside of update panel. Check here for further information about update panel [[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386454(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386454%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) ]

Comment: I am using Nested UpdatePanel, and timr tick event is panel that is inside one

Comment: You sure your UpdatePanel is not conditional?

Comment: @VitorCanova My timer is not conditional, It needs to be updated Always